# VUEJS and Vuetify - Push the results from a localbase into a data table

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

How do i push my results into a data object please

I would like to push the :key to the id field and the :data to map across to my other data fields

my data object is called orgs: []

I have the following data returned from my get query

```
[{…}]
0:
data: {person: 'John', orgName: 'test', due: 'this is due'}
key: "11ed25ccf7548160bff2ab4c1d56ee40"
```

I have tried

```
this.$db.collection('orgs').get({ keys: true })
      .then
      (response => { 
          console.log('orgs: ', response) <--- this displays the results
          this.orgs.forEach(response => {
            const data = {
              'person': response.data.person,
              'orgName': response.data.orgName,
              'due': response.data.due,
              'id': response.key
            }
            this.orgs.push(data) 
        })
      });
```

I get no errors but my this.orgs data item remains empty so assume I am not updating the array for some reason

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to populate it in a simple way as follows

```
this.$db.collection('orgs').get({ keys: true })
  .then
  (response => { 
      this.orgs = response
      console.log('response:', this.orgs)
    })
```

Is there any issue with this approach for just getting my results or should I be using push?